# How to unit test a method, when it has handler in android

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have a method like this

```
  public void updateListViewVisibility(List<User> userList) {
      userViewVisibility.set(View.GONE);
      handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 10000000);
   }


/**
 * A runnable code, the purpose of this is to display a message if no user found in range.
 */
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        changeState();
    }
};
```

I can run the unit test of this , if there is no handler in the method `updateListViewVisibility`

```
@Test
public void test_updateupdateListViewVisibility() {
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    userList.clear();
    SUT.updateListViewVisibility(userList);
    assertEquals("Variable userViewVisibility should be false",
            SUT.userViewVisibility.get(), false);
}
```

But , if I keep the handler

I got the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method postDelayed in android.os.Handler not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

How can unit test that method properly?

Comment: Handler comes from the android framework. you would need to have espresso tests or useroboelectric in that case

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, Run your Test class MockitoJunitRunner

eg: `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class WhateverClassTest { }`

and mock the handler

```
@Mock
Handler handler
```

// add these dependencies to gradle:

```
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Above solution getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Method obtain in android.os.Message not mocked".exception

Answer (score 0):

```
val handler: Handler = mock(Handler::class.java)
```

if you don't need to execute the runnable code block, so just return true.

```
`when`(handler.post(any(Runnable::class.java))).thenReturn(true)
```

if you need to execute the runnable code block so, use

```
`when`(handler.post(any(Runnable::class.java))).thenAnswer {
            (it.arguments[0] as? Runnable)?.run()
            true
        }
```